# Why adapter in a grid view is not updating its content?

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

I have a Tree structure where nodes are categories if they have children and items if not.
I drew the top level categories using a gridView and a custom adapter.
I registered a click event handler where I change the level of the tree and notify the gridView that the data has changed.

Snippet:

```
gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    ma = new MenuAdapter(this, menu); //menu is the tree I pass to the adapter
    gridview.setAdapter(ma);

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {
            //ma.setSubTree(position);
            menu = menu.children.get(position);
            gridview.deferNotifyDataSetChanged();
            gridview.invalidateViews();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + position,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Using stdout to debug it appears the tree position is indeed updated but the view remains the same.
This leads me to believe that the mistake I made is in the adapter's getView method but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

The getView inflates a custom layout (Image thumb and TextView) from data of each Tree node.

Snippet:

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View gridView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        gridView = new View(mContext);
        gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);

        TextView textView = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.gridItemText);
        textView.setPadding(15, 15, 15, 15);
        textView.setText(menu.children.get(position).toString());

        com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.BootstrapCircleThumbnail thumb = (com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.BootstrapCircleThumbnail) gridView.findViewById(R.id.thumb);
        thumb.setImage(menu.children.get(position).imageSource);
    } else {

        gridView = (View) convertView;
    }
    return gridView;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't you use an `ExpandableListView`, for a **tree** structure?

Comment: I don't want it to expand. I might have chosen a wrong layout but once the users picks a category I want to display only that category preferably with pictures of items.

Comment: A master-detail design, maybe? You have a ListView or GridView for the Categories. When an item is clicked another Fragment (detail) replaces the master one, showing the selected category items.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will take a look at that and maybe change. But I suspect the problem will persist as updating the tree will still be needed.

Answer (score 2):

You should reflect data change to view even if convertView is null.
Pseudo code:

```
if(convertView == null) {
    convertView = inflater.inflate(...);
}
// update view below
// set your textView etc.
```

When convertView is null, you create for it, when it's not null, means you created before, and android pass this dirty view to getView, so you need to update it to reflect underlying data. View creation and View configuration are different things.

Comment: Your profile info shows you have 9 answers and 0 upvotes.
Here, have my upvote, good sir :) and welcome to stackoverflow

Comment: @Tawcharowsky Wow, I have never expected that, thanks!